# How recovery modified files in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, revision-history

I'm working at an important project.
I have modified some php and css files and uploads theme.
Then, i have deleted cache and the project doesn't works.
I'd like recovery files at the point first the modify.
Is there a way? 
Excuse me for my english.

Comment: If it is really important project, I believe that You use some kind of  repositories :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't say which version of Netbeans you're using but if it's a recent one you can try to use the "*Local History*" feature.

That functionality has moved a bit in recent versions but if it's available there should be a *History*  option using Right-Click on the file in the *Projects* browser. Or also, from the menu *Team* > *Local History*.

Right-click again on the proper version in history should show an option to revert to that version.