# Is there a way to recover a file went dead after a power outage?

Tags: php, netbeans, windows-7, file-recovery

I was just developing a website on NetBeans 7.4, using `PHP`, i have saved the file a dozen times before by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

The **millisecond** i hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> again to save my last changes on the file, a *power outage* happens, and my computer just went off. (Yeah, i'm so lucky.)

After a while, the power came back on, and i opened my computer to see all the file is gone.

I had hundreds of lines of code and (stupidly) didn't use git or any CVS for the project. The other files are just fine, but my computer went off while it was writing into the file i was working on (`home.php`).

I took a screenshot because i can't copy and paste the contents, as it's a bunch of NULL's on line 1.
`home.php` :

[image: home.php screenshot]

My question is, is there any way i can recover this file, or did i just lose my 3.5 hours of work?

I've tried

- **To look for the file in windows cache**

  - *404 : my file wasn't there.*
- **To look for the file in netbeans' own cache directory.**

  - *404 : my file wasn't there either*
- **To look for the output in chrome cache**

  - *404 : no chance.*
- **System recovery**

  - *That didn't help because i don't have a restore point for 4 hours ago.*

Comment: If the file's content has been *overwritten* then you're pretty much screwed as to trying to recover any data - this is because the block data and/or internal file structure is entirely trashed. Anyway, time to use git/hg (or any other dvcs that encourages many local change-sets) and an environment that has automatic backups .. also maybe a UPS :)

Comment: I've been googling for hours, i think you're right. giving up on this one. Just started as a playground project, that's why i didn't use a vcs at the first place

Comment: See if you can access the [NetBeans Local History](http://humansky.com/2012/05/netbeans-local-history-to-the-rescue/) (ref. https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/LocalHistory/) - if it *was* enabled, then previous versions of the file *might* be available. If it wasn't enabled then .. live and learn .. and enable it.

Comment: Thank you, but as i said i didn't use a cvs, so that couldn't help.

Comment: The [*Local History*](https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/LocalHistory/#Figure1) should be available even without CVS, no? (CVS/SVN versioning is separate from *Local* versioning.) See also [How recovery modified files in netbeans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142052/how-recovery-modified-files-in-netbeans/15150852#15150852)

Comment: It *should* be there, as i'm using a recent version (7.4 to be specific) of NB, but i can't find "Local History" anywhere, i've looked at main toolbar, project tree->context menu, searched in help and options and project preferences, found out that it *was* on, gave me hope.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47302/discussion-between-seckin-and-user2864740)

Comment: I've no idea how to use NB 7 :( It's a shame that the Local History isn't easy to access. If it *is* enabled, then it *should* be accessible somewhere, but from where (or how) I know not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, if the file's contents have been overwritten, then there's not much you can do.

You could try and find an earlier version of your file using data recovery software and performing a deep scan of your drive. This will look for data that is not tied to a file (i.e. an earlier version of your work).

You could try:

- [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva): small and free, feature rich, gets the job done
- [GetDataBack](https://www.runtime.org/): not free, but highly effective (I've used it in the past, was quite satisfied with the results)
- There's also a wikipedia article on data recovery software [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_recovery_software), where you can check many other options

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'm trying Recuva right now, i hope i can get my code back. I'll update you with the results.

Comment: I have successfully recovered a big portion of my file using Recuva! Thank you!

Comment: Use Recuva for windows with advance option "corrupted files" search and it will restore the file for good.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click the file and check for the older version Named as Previous Version or Restore Previous version, it will restore fraction of your file but not complete.

This might guide you: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/recover-data-files-in-windows-7-with-previous-versions/4992/

Comment: Right Click *where*? Somewhere in Netbeans? In Windows Explorer?

Comment: on explorer. Right click at home.php

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't help, i have no previous versions of neither the file, nor the folder contains it.