# Restoring java file in netbeans after crash

Tags: java, netbeans, restore

I've been programming using NetBeans 8.0.2. I was working on a file when my PC crashed, now the file is corrupted and in NotePad its filled with 
"NULNULNULNULNULNUL.....", in NetBeans there is nothing visible except the red error-line (illegal character: 'u0000'). 
Is there any way to restore the file?

[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/1553zub.jpg]

Hope theres a way to get it back, thanks in advance.

edit: Netbeans doesnt show any previous versions in local history.

Comment: This is probably a good time to learn about version control.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How recovery modified files in netbeans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142052/how-recovery-modified-files-in-netbeans)

Comment: Not sure what the fuss is all about. Any decent IDE would give you a local history feature and this question has already been asked multiple times on the site.

Comment: Also a good time to learn about the importance of frequent backup.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Source file and check history tab,
this may be the solution,just try it

Comment: The history tab for this file is empty although I've been working on it for a couple days.